# tar a result of wget

Tags: pipe, tar, wget

I want to `wget` a file and `tar` it, in one command, I guess it is simple but I can't get it done. I tried several things.

```
wget <url> | tar -cvz file.gz.tar -

tar -cvzf file.tar `wget <url>`

wget -qO <url> | tar -cvf file.tar

wget <url> -O - | tar
```

Any help?

Comment: Your are downloading a single file or a sub-site (wget -r..)?

Comment: Some sites let you `wget -S --header="accept-encoding: gzip" url` and obtain the gziped file; For a single file,   file.gzip is a more natural solution than file.tgz.

Comment: Tarring(?) a single file does nothing but waste bytes. Gzip OTOH may be what you want

Comment: Tar itself just merges multiple files into one file, which you don't want to do if you only have one file. Just use gzip to compress *without* tarring. There is no reason to use `xxx.tar.gz` instead of `xxx.gz ` if you only have one file.

Comment: Downvoted: Accepted answer does not match what is asked for in the question. If you do not care about actually 'tar'-ing your download, please consider fixing.

Comment: @inVader That's the first time I see an OP being downvoted for accepting an answer.

Comment: @ giannis christofakis, no downvote for accepting question. It's just that the question does obviously not ask for what they were actually looking for. OP does not seem to be interested in tar-ing the download. Hence, the question itself is flawed since there is a mismatch between question and (accepted) answer which needs to be corrected. This will make it easier for others with similar problems to find an adequate solution.

Comment: @inVader Then why don't you downvote the ones who answered the question?

Comment: @giannis christofakis In fact I tried that, too but I seem to be not eligible to do so at the moment. However, accepting one of them clearly indicates that this is what you were looking for, not tar-ing, or at least that it is an accepatable alternative. Which is totally fine with me, but I think the question should reflect that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Do you really want to `tar` the file or are you looking for downloading a file into a compressed form. Tarring a file is just bundling (uncompressed) files into an (uncompressed) archive. If you want to download a file into a compressed file you can use:

`wget -qO - <url>|gzip -c - > file.gz`

Answer (score 8):

You can't deal with input streams in that way. It is designed to deal with *files*. If you had managed to create an archive as you describe, what would it look like? How would you untar it? There would be no filename to create, just data.

I think your best bet is to get the file and tar it in two separate commands. If you don't want the file to remain on your drive, you can use tar's `--remove-files` flag:

```
wget http://example.com/filename && tar cvzf file.tgz --remove-files filename
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I must disagree there tar is perfectly capable of dealing with input and output streams both reading and writing files, in fact my usual mode of operation for using the aur on Archlinux before I get cower installed is to use curl to download the tarball for it to the output stream type it into tar xz

Comment: @ntzrmtthihu777 yes but,  presumably,  you then redirect that to a file,  you don't use the -f option to give a file name.

Comment: nope. `curl some://url/package.tar.gz | tar xf` with no redirection

Comment: @ntzrmtthihu777 well yes, but that's totally different. You are receiving compressed data as input, and saving into a tarfile as output. The OP wants to receive _text_ and pass that to tar. Try `curl some://url/file.html | tar xf`. That will fail.

Comment: obviously. x is for decompression. Smart-aleky-ness aside, you are correct; I was misrecalling some experimentation I was doing with gzip. My prior point stands, however, that tar can read and write to stdout and stdin.

Comment: @ntzrmtthihu777 fair enough, that first sentence was misleading. Yes, of course tar can deal with input streams, just not in the way that the OP was expecting. Yes, `tar c file > foo.tar` will work. I don't think it can _read_ from stdin though but there might be a convoluted way. This is tar after all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22242/discussion-between-ntzrmtthihu777-and-terdon).

Answer (score 3):

This is not going to work the way you want it to. A file (obviously with a filename) needs to be stored in the tar. That bit (the filename) is obviously missing if you just pipe the contents of the download to `tar`. I don't see any way to tell `tar` that it should pack `stdin` and specify a filename for that.

That said, I really do not see a way to achieve that with standard unix commands. Obviously, you might be able to write something yourself instead, for example using `python` and the `request` and `tarfile` modules which should not be to difficult if you are a bit handy with coding.

Until then, or if you have to rely on the available unix commands, you will need to stick to downloading to a temporary file, taring, then deleting the file. To not need to specify the filename multiple times, I would suggest using a variable:

```
DOWNLOAD=<FILENAME>; wget <DOMAIN>/$DOWNLOAD && tar -cvf $DOWNLOAD.tar --remove-files $DOWNLOAD
```

Answer (score 1):

```
wget -qO - <url> |gzip -c > file_name.gz
```

`-c` for stdout . that's `>` used. the file get from wget serialize to file_name.gz using standard output library.

`-qO` to send output file